# Reuse Object Reference in a Template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like this:

```
app.directive("myData", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "myTemplate.html"
    };
});
```

Then in myTemplate.html I have something like:

```
<input type="number"
       ng-if="(getMyObject(item.DataId)).Valid"
       ng-model="(getMyObject(item.DataId)).Price"/>

<div ng-bind="(getMyObject(item.DataId)).Price"
     ng-if="!(getMyObject(item.DataId).Valid"></div>
```

This directive is placed inside an `ng-repeat` (hence the `item.`).

My question is how can I store the object I get from `getMyObject()` somewhere so I don't have to call it repeatedly? I tried to use `ng-init` as:

```
<p ng-init="dataObject=getMyObject(item.DataId)"/>
```

and reference it like:

```
<input type="number"
       ng-if="dataObject.Valid"
       ng-model="dataObject.Price"/>

<div ng-bind="dataObject.Price"
     ng-if="!dataObject.Valid"></div>
```

But this doesn't work once I submit any changes and change the data in the model since the `ng-init` only works on the first time when the page loads.

Comment: what is happening in getMyObject such that it matters if you call it repeatedly? if you need an expression to determine what you bind or to use in an ng-if. What does it matter if you call that function multiple times

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well enough. Because the page is quite big and I have nested ng-repeat so I'm trying to optimize the code for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up the one time binding in your linking function:

```
app.directive("myData", function() {
  return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "myTemplate.html",
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.dataObject = scope.getMyObject(scope.item.DataId);
      }
  };
});
```

This way you will have one `dataObject` per instanciation of your directive, but only computed once. Now if you need to "recompute" this `dataObject` after some change, you could do that in a function or on a watcher:

```
link: function(scope) {
  scope.dataObject = scope.getMyObject(scope.item.DataId);

  // Option 1
  scope.$watch('somethingToWatch', function() {
    scope.dataObject = scope.getMyObject(scope.item.DataId);
  });

  // Option 2 (choose one or the other)
  scope.onSubmit = function() {
    scope.dataObject = scope.getMyObject(scope.item.DataId);
  };
}
```